# Prestashop - Show the prices are tax excluded for visitors

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am on Prestashop 1.6

When a user is a guest or a member, the mention "tax excl." is displayed next to the price in the products sheets.

Like this :

[image]

I would like this text to appear also for the visitors.

For visitors, it currently shoows like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think I found the solution. In product.tpl, replace

```
<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="{$productPrice}">{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}</span>
                                   {if $tax_enabled  && ((isset($display_tax_label) && $display_tax_label == 1) || !isset($display_tax_label))}
                                        {if $priceDisplay == 1} {l s='tax excl.'}{else} {l s='tax incl.'}{/if}
                                    { /if}
```

With :

```
<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="{$productPrice}">{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}</span>
                                        {if $priceDisplay == 1} {l s='tax excl.'}{else} {l s='tax incl.'}{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

So go to Client -> Group and for all groups choose as price display the HT.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

In Back office, customers > groups choose the visitor group click to modify button, change the tax display to tax incl, if it is like that, go to admin coutries choose your country, click to modify button and enable tax showing [image]

Comment: Thanks but tax showing is already displayed for every countries, and Visitors are already in "Tax excluded" mode, as I want. But the problem is just that the label "tax excl." is still not showing for visitors.

Comment: @CaptainHarlock have you something like that in your product.tpl file
 
   {if $tax_enabled  && ((isset($display_tax_label) && $display_tax_label == 1) || !isset($display_tax_label))}
           {if $priceDisplay == 1} {l s='tax excl.'}{else} {l s='tax incl.'}{/if}
          {/if}

Comment: Yes, that is the case